# How do I get modulus and exponent from public key for signature verification?

Tags: php, rsa, digital-signature, gnupg, pgp

I've signed the string `test` using a public key.

I got the information from the public key like owner name, key id and fingerprint and the public key itself.

Now I try to verify the signature.

I get the right structure for the v4 signature starting with 137 ...

http://senderek.ie/research/security/key-experiments.html

```
<?php
$signature = "iQIcBAEBCAAGBQJWSZmTAAoJENJgM+p1pSbP7xoQAKStiaQlKrltTKGzfVVLw3nE
    bKkEkb7Wn2wCIOUSov2ACvgDYtnUelt9K6iSY4OcpetVU0UQi1xKuLbZWgoXs6R6
    0rGUBitp5zaHtwthMciUPW9LMjPx+lLtrDdJt/PGZXqBLVlWSITzJsI4PLZ1JL5j
    xopZYSioK/Rji6WHDW6JaYuwPnbO5xH6trv5g03vE1GFUfAw+TpLGJYiUGkaRoD5
    sLOR7R+digOJA4MDcnq5wTyf4tit+fG8HuqUUITyQ/fQ5R8zeN2sj8ZhIKLMXV5G
    DOtV7L1iYQazL3orYXIABWxY80+j2+e265d9UGxthij6nxcEdf/uIRUxD3gZhvXV
    SXziv0lTmKnSElK52oW+JPXbLhZ3qxhBf0zWBHtRAo3zKdS506UEQlyGK7HILvzh
    4jLjsaLrcjbAxUiG4wdNjgGAaFnW0lSjUvFqeRE2UqLRMTRKdjZ3jFjo/xmTrhXV
    +VkX7KWWf5cmUBycvdR6q+UvQi6ADx+nDXtOXHz6gQ3cLpsuUVf6GZXmoPpZV1nk
    Uk5Cp0i8LlXFlQjdYjSbhAuipxXOdvdN3sCMuAXIWdfAfqbm2tYhV9/7qjrllx/M
    Ecj2Tw27rpVCXuZe6dJfVnDZLqaWup7EgnAYo9/RGGPc+J5H9yiClc3ewOMDSElN
    SnsNN+bQxBa9TNMzrD6w
    =8Y2I";

$s = base64_decode($signature);
$sa = str_split($s);
$subpacket_data = 0;
$data = '';
$subpacket_data_un = 0;
for ($i = 0;$i < strlen($s);)
{
    ord($sa[$i++]);

    if ($i == 3) $version = ord($sa[$i]);
    if ($i == 4) $sig_type = ord($sa[$i]);
    if ($i == 5) $key_alg = ord($sa[$i]);
    if ($i == 6) $hash_alg = ord($sa[$i]);
    if ($i == 7) $subpacket_data = ord($sa[$i]) << 8;
    if ($i == 8) $subpacket_data += ord($sa[$i]);
    if ($i == 8 + $subpacket_data + 1) $subpacket_data_un = ord($sa[$i]) << 8;
    if ($i == 8 + $subpacket_data + 2) $subpacket_data_un += ord($sa[$i]);
    if ($i == 8 + $subpacket_data_un + 1) $left_bit = ord($sa[$i]) << 8;
    if ($i == 8 + $subpacket_data_un + 2) $left_bit_2 = ord($sa[$i]);

}

$subpacket_data_raw = ord($sa[9]) << 40;
$subpacket_data_raw .= ord($sa[10]) << 32;
$subpacket_data_raw .= ord($sa[11]) << 24;
$subpacket_data_raw .= ord($sa[12]) << 16;
$subpacket_data_raw .= ord($sa[13]) << 8;
$subpacket_data_raw .= ord($sa[14]);

$signing_string = "test" . $version . $sig_type . $key_alg . $hash_alg . $subpacket_data . $subpacket_data_raw);
```

But what is next? Where and which values do I need from the public key for the signature algorithm?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-2.2
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.3
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.2.4

> All signatures are formed by producing a hash over the signature
> data, and then using the resulting hash in the signature algorithm.

Detected signature algorithm is RSA.

So theoretically I just need the input parameters for some RSA-function? But where are they stored?

The code is just an example and I am just using it for testing, I know that I can and should change some lines.

I have these packets of the public key:

```
0) int(153) = Tag
1) int(2) = H Length
2) int(13) = L Length
3) int(4) = Version
4) int(85) = Creation Time (<<24) +
5) int(12) = Creation Time (<<16) +
6) int(54)  = Creation Time (<<8) +
7) int(60)  = Creation Time
8) int(1) = PK algorithm
9) int(16) = MPI Modulus n (<<8?)
10) int(0) = MPI Modulus n
```

is this right? What do I have to do with the next packets? How many packets do I need for the MPI Modulus n number?

> A Multi-Precision-Integer is a very long number with the length in
> bits stored in the first two bytes followed by all the bits that make
> up the entire number.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to use a library like OpenSSL.

Comment: Sure, but the library I contribute to uses pure PHP functions, no dependencies like other libraries or PHP extensions. I know there there is also a pure PHP implementation of RSA in phpseclib. So we do not really need any OpenSSL extension or library ;-) My question is about the actual parameters needed for the RSA function call and where I can find them in the public key ;-)

Comment: As OpenSSL is bundled by default I would just use it. Any reason why you're implementing this on your own?

Comment: But that would not help me with my question anyway. So this would make no difference. There are reasons why phpseclib exists.